# Memory Lock Error in Linux

Tags: linux

While running a tool, I am getting the following error in tool console. Can someone please help me with this error?
"Cannot lock file /path/to/.run.reg. Your system has run out of locks"

Comment: What is the tool? Please edit your question to include the output of `ulimit -a`.

Comment: Attie, I am using Pegasus Tool  for LVS verification.